# Spring Webservice Template Response Time

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, spring-ws

I am using Spring WebserviceTemplate to make external soap calls.

```
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
```

I am observing that when the size of request payload increases the response time increases drastically. Some of these calls are taking more than 20 seconds (276 KB XML Data). The service that is called returns the response within a second. I also tried mocking the service call by running a stubbed service using SOAP UI in my local machine.In all the cases , the response time increases with increase in payload size.

What happens within "marshallSendAndRecieve" that could potentitally cause this delay and are there recommendations that I could try to fix this?

Comment: Ofcourse it will take longer to unmarshall a large XML response. A lot of mapping/conversion is going on. Also do you really want to have such a large payload in memory directly?

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. Are there any alternatives while using webservicetemplate?

Comment: Have you done some profiling to determine where the time is spent?